# Using a variable to add a data frame column in R

Tags: r, variables, substitution

I am trying to achieve the following

```
stocks <- c('AXP', 'VZ', 'V')
library('quantmod')
getSymbols(stocks)
```

Above command creates 3 data variables named AXP, VZ, and V

```
prices <- data.frame(stringAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Here I am trying to create a column with name as ticket (e.g. AXP) with data in 
The following should add 3 columns to the frame, names AXP, VZ, and V with data in 
AXP$AXP.Adjusted, VZ$VZ.Adjusted, V$V.Adjusted

```
for (ticker in stocks)
{
  prices$ticker <- ticker$ticker.Adjusted
}
```

How do I achieve this? R gives an error like this when I try this

```
Error in ticker$ticker.Adjusted : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler way to do this

```
do.call('cbind', lapply(mget(stocks), function(d) d[,6]))
```

Explanation:

1. `mget(stocks)` gets the three data frames as a list
2. `lapply` extracts the 6th column which contains the variable of interest.
3. `do.call` passes the list from (2) to `cbind`, which binds them together as columns.

NOTE: This solution does not take care of the different number of columns in the data frames.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question before, now I think I understood what you want:

What you wrote does not work because the object `ticker` is character string. If you want to get the object named after that string, you have to evaluate the parsed text.

Try this:

```
for (ticker in stocks){
      prices <- cbind(prices, eval(parse(text=ticker))[,paste0(ticker, ".", "Adjusted")])

}
```

This will give you:

```
An ‘xts’ object on 2007-01-03/2014-01-28 containing:
  Data: num [1:1780, 1:4] 53.4 53 52.3 52.8 52.5 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "AXP.Adjusted" "AXP.Adjusted.1" "VZ.Adjusted" "V.Adjusted"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ src    : chr "yahoo"
 $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2014-01-29 01:06:51"
```

Comment: Works too, like the simpler version with mget but I get the idea now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One problem you're going to have is that the three downloads have different number of rows, so binding them all into a single data frame will fail.

The code below uses the last 1000 rows of each file (most recent), and does not use loops.

```
stocks <- c('AXP', 'VZ', 'V')
library('quantmod')
getSymbols(stocks)

prices=do.call(data.frame,
               lapply(stocks,
                      function(s)tail(get(s)[,paste0(s,".Adjusted")],1000)))
colnames(prices)=stocks
head(prices)
#              AXP    VZ     V
# 2010-02-08 34.70 21.72 80.58
# 2010-02-09 35.40 22.01 80.79
# 2010-02-10 35.60 22.10 81.27
# 2010-02-11 36.11 22.23 82.73
# 2010-02-12 36.23 22.15 82.38
# 2010-02-16 37.37 22.34 83.45
```

Working from the inside out, `s` is the ticker (so, e.g., `"AXP"`); `get(s)` returns the object with that name, so `AXP`; `get(s)[,paste0(s,".Adjusted")]` is equivalent to `AXP[,"AXP.Adjusted"]`; `tail(...,1000)` returns the last 1000 rows of `...`. So when s="AXP", the function returns the last 1000 rows of `AXP$AXP.Adjusted`.

`lapply(...)` applies that function to each element in stocks.

`do.call(data.frame,...)` invokes the data.frame function with the list of columns returned by `lapply(...)`.